# Trying to find all hastag count and inserting a amount in MYSQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, count, find

I use PHP and MYSQL database.

Oke so I have 2 tables, one is called `discover_section` and the other is called `videos`.
I want to set the amount of found corresponding hastags (in `videos`) in the `discover_section`.

For example the amount of #plantAtree hastags is found 20 times in the `video` section. Now I want to set that amount in the `discover_section` column. Then go to the next hastag found in the `discover_section` (#test) and look how many times that is found in the `video` table etc.

How do I do this?

My tables look like the following:

discover_section:

[image: discover_section]

videos:

[image: videos]

Comment: Provide tables DDLs (as CREATE TABLE, skip unnesessary columns), some sample data (as INSERT INTO), show desired output for this data with explanations.

Comment: You should start by [normalizing](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/) your database instead of storing multiple values (like the tags) in one single column. You basically have one table with the videos, one with all the tags and one "many-to-many" table that links the videos to the tags. This would make it very easy to get the aggregated data you're asking for. Storing multiple values in one column is a bad practice that will def. make easy and basic things harder.

Comment: I know that it makes things harder, but I cant change it anymore. I need to change a lot of code if i change the layouts of the tables... In my next project I will keep this more organized, but for now i have to deal with this mess :P

Comment: It's not just about it making things harder, it also hurts performance doing it like this since you won't be able to take advantage of indexes in the same way. Since you still seem to be working on this project, I would still recommend taking the time to actually refactor the database. In the end, you will thank yourself for doing it.

Comment: Thank you magnus, I will consider this option. Not sure how I am going to do that because both have their own functionality in my app. Also I dont want to call this function over and over again. maybe once or twice a day... This function will be sorting (via amount of hastags found) if the hastag is trending or not.

Answer (score 0):

At first I have to agree with @MagnusEriksson. You should normalize your database. Then this would be very easy and fast. Also note that I'm absolutely not a SQL pro. I know that subquerys are bad for performance. So my solution is probobly quite slow compared to others.

The idea is to check, if the hashtag is contained in the `video.description` by comparing strings. The hashtag can either be the only string in this field, it can be the starting string, the end string or the center string. All hashtags are separated by spaces. This check is performed by four different conditions.

The code below, also executable at https://sqltest.net/#1109083, shows how to select the hashtag count.

```sql
SELECT
    discover_section.*,
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(id) 
        FROM 
            video
        WHERE
            -- only one hashtag saved
            video.description LIKE TRIM(discover_section.section_name) OR 
            -- searched hashtag is the last hashtag, separator is space
            video.description LIKE CONCAT("% ", discover_section.section_name) OR
            -- searched hashtag is the first hashtag, separator is space
            video.description LIKE CONCAT(discover_section.section_name, " %") OR
            -- searched hashtag is one of the ceter hashtag, separator is space
            video.description LIKE CONCAT("% ", discover_section.section_name, " %")
    ) AS amount
FROM 
    discover_section;
```

To move those four conditions into one, one can use a regular expression. This does the same checks as above. (Again, also interactive here: https://sqltest.net/#1109084)

```sql
SELECT
    discover_section.*,
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(id) 
        FROM 
            video
        WHERE
            video.description REGEXP CONCAT("(^|\\s+)", discover_section.section_name, "(\\s+|$)")
    ) AS amount
FROM 
    discover_section;
```

To change this into updating `discover_section`, the code has to be modified like the following (works the same for the non-regexp code):

```sql
UPDATE
    discover_section
SET amount =
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(id) 
        FROM 
            video
        WHERE
            video.description REGEXP CONCAT("(^|\\s+)", discover_section.section_name, "(\\s+|$)")
    );
```

Note that there are problems with hashtags like `#!`, `#(` and so on sice those characters (`!`, `(`) are used in regular expressions. But I guess hashtags are alphanumeric only. If not you have to check if there is an escape function.

Comment: First of all... let me tell you... YOU ARE AWESOME!! :D thank you very much for this answer and the interactive examples. I use your code like you see underneath this message. I will call this 2 or 3 times a day so it is not that heavy on stuff. Again miile7... you are a blessing!! thank you!!

Comment: @MarbleToyRacingTV That is nice to hear. You are welcome :) Maybe you can mark this question as solved by clicking the tick on the top left corner of my answer. This way this question is not shown as "new" and "unanswered" anymore. Plus I get some reputation for it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
    discover_section
SET amount =
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(id) 
        FROM 
            videos
        WHERE
                        -- only one hashtag saved
            videos.description LIKE TRIM(discover_section.section_name) OR 
            -- searched hashtag is the last hashtag, separator is space
            videos.description LIKE CONCAT("% ", discover_section.section_name) OR
            -- searched hashtag is the first hashtag, separator is space
            videos.description LIKE CONCAT(discover_section.section_name, " %") OR
            -- searched hashtag is one of the ceter hashtag, separator is space
            videos.description LIKE CONCAT("% ", discover_section.section_name, " %")
    );
```